# Fallo en query para la hoja de calculo de google

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-query-language

Estoy realizando una query para la hoja de calculo de google y me esta dando fallo en la ultima parte de esta. La query funciona con 3 datos que se insertan mediante validacion en las casillas B1,D1 Y B2.

Esto es lo que tengo:

`=if(AND(B1=0;B2=0;D1=0);IMPORTRANGE("LINK"; "Llista!A6:S1000");if(AND(B1>1;B2>1;D1=0);query(IMPORTRANGE("LINK"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6='"&B1&"' and Col8='"&B2&"'");query(IMPORTRANGE("LINK"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6 IN('"&B1&"','"&D1&"') and Col8='"&B2&"'")))`

Esta es la parte que me falla:

`query(IMPORTRANGE("LINK"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6 IN('"&B1&"','"&D1&"') and Col8='"&B2&"'")))`

El error que me da es:

No se puede analizar la cadena de la consulta para En la función QUERY, el parámetro 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "Col6 "" at line 1, column 16. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...

Modifico la linea para solucionar el error anterior "creo"

`query(IMPORTRANGE("LINK"; "Llista!A6:S1000");"select * where Col6 IN"("'"&B1&"','"&D1&"'")" and Col8='"&B2&"'")))`

Y me da el error:

Error de análisis de fórmula.

Esta ultima parte, deberia seleccionar los datos que tengan la categoria B1 Y D1 y filtrarlos por la zona B2.

Por ejemplo B1 y D1 son rangos de policia y  B2 donde estan destinados.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado, simplemente google no soporta la utilizacion de IN por lo que me queda asi:

`=query(IMPORTRANGE("LINK";"Llista!A6:S1000"); "select * where (Col6 ='"&B1&"' or Col6 = '"&D1&"') and Col8 ='"&B2&"'")`